# Connect two physical computers with Apache Thrift

Tags: thrift

I am new to Apache Thrift and I am in a college project where I need to connect a C++ server and a C# client with Apache Thrift.

I can connect both of them when they are running in the same PC. From the beginning, the tutorial with:

```
TTransport transport = new TSocket("localhost",9090);
TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
Analizador.Client client = new Analizador.Client(protocol);
```

But I need to separate them, one in a PC running Linux and the another in a Windows-running PC, so both of them are in the same network. How or where do I need to configure to make this happen?

To be more specific: The main PC is running Windows and inside is a virtual machine running Ubuntu 16.04 which has a running C++ server with:

```
int port = 9090;
shared_ptr<AnalizadorHandler> handler(new AnalizadorHandler());
shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new AnalizadorProcessor(handler));
shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port));
shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

TSimpleServer server(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory);
server.serve();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"localhost"` specifies that the client will connect to the server on the same machine. First open a command prompt on the Windows machine and make sure `ping 192.168.56.1` works.

As JensG said, use the code:

`TTransport transport = new TSocket("192.168.56.1", 9090);`

Comment: thanks for you response, so if my virtual machine have the ip 192.168.56.1 i need to put that in the localhost atribute?

Comment: @EdwinAguilar: Yes, `TTransport transport = new TSocket("192.168.56.1",9090);` should do, given the IP is correct If it still does not work, you may want to check firewall settings. The name `localhost` is just a [shorthand for the local machine, or `127.0.0.1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).